# Getting errors while trying to decode string with rsa and base64

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to make a password manager with Python and encrypting the passwords with RSA. that part went smoothly. What's not going smoothly is the decryption.
This is the code for the encryption

```
def encode(message_to_send):
    b_message = message_to_send.encode()
    encrypted = rsa.encrypt(b_message, publicKey)
    encrypted_b64 = base64.b64encode(encrypted)
    encrypted_b64_string = encrypted_b64.decode()
    return(encrypted_b64_string)
```

I've saved the passwords in a text file and I'm taking them from the text file using this chunk of code

```
if os.path.isfile('passwords.txt'):
    with open('passwords.txt', 'r') as f:
        tempPass = f.read()
        tempPass = tempPass.split(',')
        passwords = [x for x in tempPass if x.strip()]
        for app in passwords:
            print(decode(app))
```

and then decrypting it with this function called decode()

```
def decode(message_to_recieve):
    encrypted_b64 = message_to_recieve.encode()
    encrypted = base64.b64decode(encrypted_b64)
    b_final_message = rsa.decrypt(encrypted, privateKey)
    final_message = b_final_message.decode()
    return (final_message)
```

which is returning this error

```
File "/passmanager/main.py", line 64, in <module>
    print(decode(app))
  File "/passmanager/main.py", line 53, in decode
    b_final_message = rsa.decrypt(encrypted, privateKey)
  File "/home/horia/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rsa/pkcs1.py", line 281, in decrypt
    raise DecryptionError("Decryption failed")
rsa.pkcs1.DecryptionError: Decryption failed
```

Also the publicKey and privateKey are just

```
publicKey, privateKey = rsa.newKeys(512)
```

Comment: You will have to show the *encryption* code in order to figure out why decryption isn't working.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I updated the post.

Comment: Try a few things: encrypting and immediately decrypting.  If this works, then it means the problem lies in the encoding/decoding.  If it doesn't work, then the problem lies in key generation.  If the problems are in encoding and decoding, then start printing out the encoded strings to see where they are being modified inadvertently.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is neither related to encrypting or decrypting functions nor with saving the message in encrypted form.

It is the **problem** of this part `publicKey, privateKey = rsa.newKeys(512)`, acutely the **decrypting and encrypting** part of **rsa**, will only work in your case, when both executes in one run instance or when you don't had to redefine
`publicKey, privateKey = rsa.newKeys(512)` this code block, since you are not saving the keys

In your case your taking an **input** message from user and saving it, into a text file in encrypted form, and trying to decrypt and access it later.

`rsa.newkeys(512)` 512 is the key length. When generating RSA keys, they are random every time- you can't just seed them.
I recommend reading the documentation for the function you are using

However, this doesn't satisfy your need, the password manager program is designed in a way in which you have to save the input password & access it later for that you have to save those keys somewhere, so you will be able to use them later.